# inject content script

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

i have this extension that make style changes in the opened tab..
I call a background page that injects js file.
this file includes a listener to a click event, that, when clicked, the changed starts.
here is the JS:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function() {
    alert(1);
});
```

this file works for me, but when i replace it with this:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function() {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null,
    {code:"document.body.bgColor='red !important'"});
});
```

it doesn't work..
is there any reason for that?

here is the mainfest.json:

```
{
  "name": "My First Extension",
  "version": "1.0",
  "background_page": "background1.html" ,
  "description": "The first extension that I made.",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png"  
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://*/*"]
      ,"css":   ["css/style.css"]
      ,"js": ["js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js", "js/functions.js"]
    }
  ]
  ,  
  "permissions": [
    "tabs", "http://*/*","https://*/*"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem can be in the manifest file of your extension:
http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/manifest.html

For your case you have to specify the extension [permissions](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/manifest.html#permissions) and the [content scripts](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html).

Comment: i specified the permissions and the content scripts..
i added the mainfest code up

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to inject `"document.body.style.backgroundColor='red !important'"` instead of `"document.body.bgColor='red !important'"` ?